# Getting type error 'RequiredStringSchema<string | undefined, AnyObject>' on yup validation

Tags: typescript, yup

I am encountering an issue when using the yup validation library in my Next TS project. I am receiving a type error on the type property under the PostWithSig object in my validation schema. I am unsure of the cause of this error one possibility is the name `type` itself but I am not sure about it.

Here is the error message I am receiving:

> (property) BaseSchema<any, any, any>.type: string Type
> 'RequiredStringSchema<string | undefined, AnyObject>' is not
> assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322) schema.d.ts(53, 14): The expected
> type comes from property 'type' which is declared here on type
> 'AnySchema<any, any, any>'

Here is my validation schema:

```
data: object().shape({
    createPostTypedData: object().shape({
      id: string().required(),
      expiresAt: date().required(),
      typedData: object().shape({
        types: object().shape({
          PostWithSig: array().of({
            name: string().required(),
            type: string().required(),
          }),
        }),
        domain: object().shape({
          name: string().required(),
          chainId: number().required(),
          version: string().required(),
          verifyingContract: string().required(),
        }),
        value: object().shape({
          nonce: number().required(),
          deadline: number().required(),
          profileId: string().required(),
          contentURI: string().required(),
          collectModule: string().required(),
          collectModuleInitData: string().required(),
          referenceModule: string().required(),
          referenceModuleInitData: string().required(),
        }),
      }),
    }),
  }),
```

Can anyone explain why I am encountering this error and provide a solution to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me a while to realize that you had forgot to use an object schema:

```
array().of(object().shape({
    name: string().required(),
    type: string().required(),
})),
```